# Error Message: Broken Count

Tags: package-management

I am using Ubuntu 16.4, I am not a programmer so this stuff is over my head.  When I boot computer I get Broken Count error message.  I have  tried running 'sudo apt-get clean', 'sudo apt-get autoremove', sudo rm-rf/tmp/* and apt-get autoremove, as others recommend but none of these commands work instead it asks me for my password which I don't remember.  I can't uninstall Ubuntu and reinstall because I can't remember my password.

Comment: What password are we talking here?

Comment: @GeorgeUdosen User password I suspect. Probably the OP set it to auto-login at boot.